# Lisp issues on Mac os

Tags: eclipse, lisp

I've been interested in learning lisp and rather than suck it up and trying emacs (I haven't figured that out yet), I've installed Dandelion for Eclipse.

I can't get my simple Lisp code to run

```
(* 2 3)
```

I get:

```
Error in background evaluation
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

From an older post in SuperUser I updated my `chmod` for the plugin to no avail. Does anyone know how to get this up and running?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work for you if you run SBCL in a Terminal?

Comment: Yeah it works perfectly fine. Actually, I got slime up and running in Emacs so I know that there are the requisite packages for it on my machine. It seems to just be Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Learning emacs will be the best thing since sliced bread unless you like having your editor eat 1 gig of ram. Here is some starter help I found useful.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ReferenceCards

Once you get around the emacs keyboard chords you should install slime it is worth all the eclipses in the world.

http://www.cliki.net/slime

Happy hacking !

Comment: Also you should install a real emacs from homebrew or MacPorts as the one packaged in MacOS is quite limited, though practical, not unlike mg.